# grant access to folder to 2 linux users

Tags: permissions

i have some certificate files that i want to grant to user ejabberd (group ejabberd). So I run this command

```
chown -R ejabberd:ejabberd /etc/letsencrypt/
```

I also want the www-data to be able to access them so I attempted

```
sudo usermod -a -G ejabberd www-data
```

But when I login as the `www-data user`, I cant access the `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` directory. What am I doing wrong?

```
su -l www-data -s /bin/bash
cd /etc/letsencrypt/archive
//-bash: cd: /etc/letsencrypt/archive: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at my own install, the `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` directory has permissions 0700 which disallow even the group.  Changing this to using something like `sudo chmod 0750 /etc/letsencrypt/archive` should do what you want.

Comment: thanks. I ended up using acl. ```apt install -y acl``` then ```setfacl -R -m u:ejabberd:wrx /etc/letsencrypt/```